# Kotlin getting views null in fragment when accessing the view from an Activity

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to Kotlin , I don't know what I am doing wrong. Can Any one help me ?

Fragment Code:

```
fun startViewAnimations() {
 rippleBack?.startRippleAnimation()
}
```

Activity Code:

```
override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
 when(position) {
 0 -> (pagerAdapter.getItem(position) as SearchFragment).startViewAnimations()
 }
 }
```

following is the error :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.beeland.consumer, PID: 5892
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: txt5Km must not be null
        at com.beeland.consumer.fragment.appintro.SearchFragment$startViewAnimations$1$1.run(SearchFragment.kt:56)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
```

Comment: I don't see you are accessing any views in this parts of code.

Comment: rippleBack is my view.

Comment: probably you initialize it incorrectly.

Comment: What is `txt5Km` ?

Comment: how to initialize view?

Comment: @PeterSamokhin it is a text view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using [Kotlin Android Extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html) and fragments, consider that you can call views by its' ids only in `onViewCreated` and later. If you call it before, you will see NPE.

If you don't use KAE, you can initialize view in fragment like this:

```
class MyFragment: Fragment() {

    // other methods

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val myTextView = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.my_text_view)

        // now you can do something with views
    }

    // other methods
}
```

Comment: If use KAE, you still can access views by `view.findViewById(R.id.my_text_view) as TextView`.